# Private static members and inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, static-members

So I'm working with a singleton class that wraps a few web services. The reference to the services are stored as private static readonly members. I want to have a very similar class that wraps different web service with identical interfaces. If I inherit from the first class and override the private static readonly members with new ones will everything work as smoothly as I think? Will all the inherited functions (some public, some private, some static) use the new reference?

I ask because I've ran into a couple of quirks with inheritance of static members before.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't work.  Static members are attached to the type, not an instance, and cannot be overridden.  If you change the static values (which will have to be at least `protected`, not `private`) in the derived class, that will change the values for all instances of both the base and derived classes.

The important thing to note here is that the static fields are attached to the base type.  You don't get new copies of the static fields when you derive from that base type- derived classes use the same static instances that the base class uses.

Comment: I get that they're attached to a type but methods are attached to an instance right? If an instance is of a derived class, shouldn't the methods operate with the derived class static members? Even if there are members of the same name in the base class?

Comment: The methods are attached to an instance, yes, but if the methods interact with static fields (your web service proxies, presumably), then those fields will be shared across all instances of derived and base types (and so will exhibit static-like behavior).